# Biblatex only works with [backend=bibtex]

Tags: biblatex, miktex

I have following problem and I can not find a solution for hours. I tried to use `bliblatex`, but without `[backend=bibtex]` it does not work and it says:

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> ...docsvlist \expandafter
> {\bbl@loaded }\ifboolexpr { not test {\... l.13 \begin{document} The
> control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was
> never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and
> the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and
> I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

I used PDFLaTeX -> BibTex -> PDFLaTeX. BibTex said:

> Process started
>
> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary
> file: text.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file
> text.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file text.aux I
> found no \bibstyle command---while reading file text.aux (There were 3
> error messages)
>
> Process exited normally
> ```

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsch
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Umlaute für deutsche Sprache erlaubt 
\usepackage{times} % biegt die Schriftarten schöner um


\usepackage{csquotes}               %benötigt für biblatex
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Text

\cite{KU}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis} 

\end{document}
```

My bibliography.bib is:

```
@book{KU,
 author = {Kant, Immanuel},
 title = {Werkausgabe}, 
 publisher = {Hg. v. Wilhelm Weischedel. Suhrkamp}, 
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 year = {1974},
}
```

I more or less new to LaTeX (and Texmaker), so it is quite possible that I have missed something obvious.

I've read that there could be a problem regarding UTF8 or perhaps the language pack. I even deleted German "ö" and "ä" in the .bib.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Further information:
When I use the [backend=bibtex] I get this warning:


`Package biblatex Warning: Data encoding is 'utf8'.
(biblatex) Use backend=biber.`

Comment: Well, without option `backend=bibtex`  the package `biblatex` wants informations compiled with program `biber`.  Try `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex` twice ... Then you have also no problems with the german umlauts, `biber` can handle utf-8 encoding, `bibtex` not!

Comment: I tried that, too. At the moment I'm thinking that my Texmaker can not handle biber, although I tried this [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154788#154788]

Comment: Hm, this is strange. I change to the directory where the test.tex is, confirmed by a dir, and when I try pdflatex test.tex it says:

Comment: `starting package maintenance...
installation directory: ...\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
package repository: http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: ...
going to download 20309 bytes
going to install 20 file(s) (1 package(s))

Comment: downloading http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/vertex.cab...
pdflatex: Error response from server: 404
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `test.tex'.
<*> test.tex

Comment: No matter as I use administrator or not.

Comment: I would not have thought that this really could help and it was my last solution. But, of course, it did help. I thought there would be some kind of automatic updates...

Eitherway, thank you a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was apparently solved by a MikTeX update (see accepted answer).

Comment: Note that `times` is deprecated and ought not be used in current documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in one of your comments you are using MIKTeX version `3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12`.  The current version of MiKTeX is version `3.1415926-2.3-1.40.17`, so your MiKTeX is not up to date!

Please update your TeX distribution! Best would be to install the complete MiKTeX, then you should have no problem running `biber` ...

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsch
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Umlaute für deutsche Sprache erlaubt 
\usepackage{times} % biegt die Schriftarten schöner um


\usepackage{csquotes}               %benötigt für biblatex
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

Text

\cite{KU}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis} 

\bibliographystyle{siam} % change siam to whatever style you like
\bibliography{bibliography} 

\end{document}
```

And then PDFLaTeX -> BibTex -> PDFLaTeX

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Not really. The same error (! Undefined control sequence.) and an additional one: \bibliographystyle can only be used in the preamble.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm afraid this is simply wrong. You are mixing BibTeX without Biblatex with Biblatex with Biber, but it would be wrong even if the backend was set to BibTeX. It is just confused and I suggest you delete the answer.

Comment: @SunnyBastard Actually, you should not have `\bibliographystyle` at all since you're using Biblatex. And `\bibliography{}` needs to go in the preamble. (Or use Biblatex's command, also in the preamble.)

Comment: Recent versions of biblatex use Buber by default. With those versions you need to use the [backend=bibtex] option. You also can't use many of the advanced features of biblatex.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Kurt already had the answer in the comments of my question. I just did not know how to mark it answered without an actual separated answer...

Comment: @HerbSchulz I take it you mean `Biber` ;). But this answer is wrong even if you add `backend=bibtex` or have an older version of Biblatex. Biblatex does not and never has used `\bibliographystyle{}` as far as I know. (I don't know if it has ever permitted defining the database in the document but, even if it did, this wouldn't actually print a bibliography.)